# Calculate Exponent Using only Logarithm

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I am using a website's stock screener to scan for stock meeting my critera. The criteria is to compute the Inverse of Fisher Transform (IFT) of which the equation is $\frac{e^{2x}-1}{ e^{2x}+1}$.

The probem: Inorder to be able to calculate the IFT, the exponent needs to be calcuated i.e. $e^{2x}$. The website unfortunately does not have the exponent function nor the power function. It however has $log_{10}x$ and $log_ex$ functions. My question is how can we calculate $e^{2x}$ using just the logarithms? Or is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please write out your entire problem, not just a summary.
You have obviously left out related information. Just two examples:

1. A "condition" . . . for what?

2. "The scanner". What scanner?

Comment: If the website has the power function, you can use $2.718281828459045\wedge (2 * x)$ or $7.38905609893065\wedge x$

Comment: I am afraid the website nor has the power function, hence the question. Thanks.

Comment: what language can you enter in the website? Do you have a description of the syntax? Can you write programs, loops? Sometimes the power operator is $**$ like in 2 ** 3

Comment: The site is not advance. It has default functions such as those in MS Excel rather with lesser functions.

Comment: depending on the range of x, you might be able to use a taylor series expansion [ or piecewise taylor expansion - if you can perform logical operations eg (x < 5)(x>4) ]

Comment: Excel has TANH function, which is what you want, and also POWER. Get a list of the available functions.